# Telerik grid Drop down column

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, telerik, radgrid

Below is the data which i want to use. I want to generate rad grid. If particular item is falling under same SubGroup then instead of generating labels i want to generate the dropdown list.

i.e 1st and 2nd item is having same SubGroup. So i want them to be displayed as dowpdown in rad grid.

How can i do that for all items which fall under same subgroups ?

How to provide the dataset to radgrid for this and how to handle item temple to generate dropdown and labels as per data. ?

```
Name        Price   Quantity  SubGroup  

1st  item   10.10   1         SUB   
2nd item    10.00   1         SUB   
3rd item    10.00   1         SUB2  
4th item    12.00   1         SUB2  
5th item    20.00   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the solution for your problem and here is my way to solve it:

First of all we need to prepare all nessesary events for this: 
OnNeedDatasource, OnItemBound.

In the OnNeedDatasource event, you have to pass datasource to your radgrid. At the moment i don't have better idea than List of List as Datasource. If you do it this way, you can implement grouping mechanism for datasource, so each position of main list would have X elements, if that would be more than 1 element then you would be sure, that you have to create DropDown.

When datasource is ready, you have to implement the dropdown/label item template. The best way to do it, is to create responsible column as GridTemplateColumn, and in OnItemDataBound event of radgrid, after checking if there should be label/dropdown create dynamically the control.

This is the way i actually would do this, probably there is a better way to do it. I hope my post helped you.